# Javascript console errors do not make sense

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting errors in the console relating to line 12 of my index.html file, which as you can see below is a `<script>` tag for jQuery.

[image: line12]

The errors are as follows:

[image: console]

Now, I just don't understand how this can happen, unless these files are being included dynamically within the jQuery file. However this is a standard jQuery file version 1.11.1.

Would anyone be able to explain why this occurs?

Comment: like like you include extra css styles with `src="//domain/file.css"` if you open it localy (without server) you need to specify it like `src="http://domain/file.css"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors are because you're using a protocol-less link to the CSS files when you're running the code on your local filesystem, hence the protocol becomes `file://` instead of `http://`. Change the link to those files to explicitly use `http://` and the errors will disappear.

Note that the line number itself is not correct - you need to change the references to the files noted in the error message.

Comment: I forgot to add this into my question, but there are no references to either of those files within my mark up... This site was bought as a template, which unfortunately came with errors I am now trying to fix.

Comment: In which case they may be appended dynamically by a included script. If you cannot amend that script, you would need to run this code on a webserver (either a local one or remote) for the links to work correctly. You can quite simply setup IIS on a windows machine - google for details.